# Laravel join with FIND_IN_SET

Tags: laravel-5

I am new to laravel 5.2,and i want to know more about laravel query builder,
    actually i wants to know that how can i write this SQL Query in laravel

```
SQL -> select d.*, c.*, ct.*, a.*, b.*, m.* FROM tbl_deal d
        INNER JOIN tbl_category c ON d.deal_category_id = c.category_id
        INNER JOIN tbl_brand b ON d.deal_brand_id = b.brand_id
        INNER JOIN tbl_member m ON m.member_id = d.deal_member_id       
        INNER JOIN tbl_city ct ON FIND_IN_SET(ct.city_id,d.deal_city)
        LEFT JOIN tbl_outlet o ON FIND_IN_SET(o.outlet_id,d.deal_outlets)
        LEFT JOIN tbl_area a ON a.area_id = o.outlet_area_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Please, try the query like this:

```
$result = DB::table('table_name')
        ->leftJoin('tbl_country_city', 'table_name.quiz_id', '=', 'tbl_country_city.quiz_id')
        ->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET('.$b.',field_name)')
        ->get();
```